# Why can't Allen's eye see Mimi in "D.Gray-man"?

Tags: d-gray-man

In *D.Gray-man*, why can't Allen detect Mimi with his left eye?

She is an Akuma, and Allen consistently demonstrates his ability to see Akuma before they appear, yet even when she is, say, standing on top of a building watching them in direct line-of-sight, he never sees her.

Comment: So she's watching Allen, but has Allen ever looked directly at her?

Comment: @Izkata No he hasn't; but Allen often seems to e.g. sense an Akuma behind him then turns to look.